# Как сделать сортировку map по значениям и по ключам

Tags: java, map

Делаю программу для подсчёта слов в файле. Сделал сортировку по значениям:

```
Map<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(wordCount);
        MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator(wordCount);

        Map<String, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
        newMap.putAll(wordCount);
```

создал класс который делает сортировку по значениям:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    Map<String, Integer> map;

    public MyComparator(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (map.get(o2) == map.get(o1))
            return 1;
        else
            return ((Integer) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Integer)
                    map.get(o1));

    }
}
```

и при выходе получается:

```
наше = 20
 пушкин = 20
 тигруля = 18
 полете = 18
 игрив=16
 котенок=16
 манул=12
 красив=12
```

а мне нужно чтоб все ключи с одинаковыми значениями были в алфавитном порядке. Без использования `lambda, stream`.
И еще если кто то может подсказать как из Map<String, Integer> newMap сделать String который возвращал бы значения в следующем порядке:

```
наше - 20
пушкин - 20
полете - 18
тигруля - 18
игрив - 16
котенок - 16
красив - 12
манул - 12
```

Я думал разделить ключи и значения в 2 разных листа и с помощью toString() сделать этот формат. Может есть более лёхкие пути.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструктор [`TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) принимает компаратор для типа *ключа*, а не для другого экземпляра `Map` или `Map.Entry`!

Если используется `TreeMap<String, Integer>`, то элементы этой карты уже будут отсортированы по значению ключей в алфавитном порядке, и более лёгким путём будет отсортировать поток элементов карты, которые являются `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`:

```java
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
   .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
```

Для получения строки достаточно использовать коллектор `Collectors.joining`, как было показано в [предыдущем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1344576/386633):

```java
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
   .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", e -> e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
```

---

Если нет возможностей использовать Stream API, то всё равно придётся преобразовать `entrySet` карты частоты слов в другую сортируемую коллекцию (тот же список), и сортировать уже его:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

entries.sort(new MyComparator());
```

Компаратор `MyComparator` без лямбд:

```java
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
        int reverseValueCompared = Integer.compare(e2.getValue(), e1.getValue());
        if (reverseValueCompared == 0) {
            return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
        }
        return reverseValueCompared;
    }
}
```

Для преобразования в строку к сожалению не получится использовать `String.join`, поэтому придётся написать метод для конвертации:

```java
static <K, V> String stats(Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : entries) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(e.getKey()).append(" - ").append(e.getValue());
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}

System.out.println(stats(entries));
```