# Как отсортировать Map с фильмами, по параметру внутри Values-классов?

Tags: java, сортировка, map

У меня есть класс `Film`, в котором содержится параметр количества лайков `int likes`, так же весь список фильмов содержится в структуре `HashMap<Integer filmId, Film film>`.

Помогите с сортировкой HashMap'ы по значению `likes` внутри каждого класса `Film`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [сортировка по значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457715/); [Сортировка Map по значению с сохранением результата в HashMap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358042/);;[Как сделать сортировку map по значениям и по ключам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344931/)  + ещё масса подобных вопросов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `HashMap` не поддерживает и не гарантирует порядка элементов -- поэтому **сортировка `HAshMap` невозможна**, о чём [написано в документации `java.util.HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

2. Имитировать мапу, **отсортированную по значениям**, можно только при помощи связанной хэш-мапы `LinkedHashMap`, который реализует постоянный порядок при итерации по элементам мапы при помощи двусвязного списка.  *Обычно* это порядок, в котором элементы были добавлены в мапу, на который *не влияет* повторная вставка элемента с одинаковым ключом.
   Об этом также [написано в документации `java.util.LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from `HashMap` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*).  Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is *re-inserted* into the map.

---

Исходя из вышесказанного, для сортировки *хэш-мапы* фильмов с неким целочисленным ключом по количеству лайков на фильм *в обратном порядке* следует преобразовать её в `LinkedHashMap` при помощи Stream API [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).  Для сортировки мапы по значениям по определённому полю следует использовать [`Map.Entry::comparingByValue(Comparator<V> cmp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
public static Map<Integer, Film> byFilm(
    Map<Integer, Film> films, Comparator<Film> valueComparator
) {
    return films.entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, Film>>
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(valueComparator))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            (a, b) -> a,
            LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
}
```

Соответственно, для сортировки по нужному полю достаточно вызвать эту функцию с нужным компаратором:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Film> byFilmLikesDesc(Map<Integer, Film> films) {
    return byFilm(films, Comparator.<Film>comparingInt(Film::getLikes).reversed());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно работает :)