# Как отсортировать Map<Integer, Integer> по values?

Tags: java, сортировка, map, java-stream

Есть `HashMap<Integer, Integer> mostPopularFilms;`

Содержит названия id и количество лайков, например:

1. (1, 5)
2. (2, 3)
3. (3, 0)
4. (4, 2)

Нужно отсортировать по значениям `values`, выходная структура не важна, можно поместить в `List<Integer> id`, то есть список: `[1,2,4,3]`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат [вашего же вопроса месячной давности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1509947/): [Как отсортировать Map с фильмами, по параметру внутри Values-классов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1509947/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сортировки исходной мапы по значениям и преобразования её в список следует использовать Stream API:

```java
public static List<Integer> byLikesDesc(Map<Integer, Integer> idLikeCountMap) {
    return idLikeCountMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println(byLikesDesc(Map.of(1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 0, 4, 2)));
// -> [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

---

Аналогично, можно брать поток не для элементов мапы, а для её ключей, которые можно сортировать в соответствии со значениями для данных ключей:

```java
public static List<Integer> keysByLikesDesc(Map<Integer, Integer> idLikeCountMap) {
    return idLikeCountMap.keySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(idLikeCountMap::get).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)